# Trying to identify the elements below, with differing IDs (Selenium & Python) using CSS selector or XPATH

Tags: python, selenium

Here are 3 sample elements on the page:

1. `<label class="btn btn-primary"> <input type="radio" id="Q20_0_0-A27" name="Q20_0_0" autocomplete="off" value="27" class="sr-only" onchange="$('#Q20_0_0_change').val('1');wiz.reload();" aria-describedby="Q20_0_0Text" required=""> Compliant </label>`
2. `<label class="btn btn-primary"> <input type="radio" id="Q20_1_0-A27" name="Q20_1_0" autocomplete="off" value="27" class="sr-only" onchange="$('#Q20_1_0_change').val('1');wiz.reload();" aria-describedby="Q20_1_0Text" required=""> Compliant </label>`
3. `<label class="btn btn-primary"> <input type="radio" id="Q20_2_0-A27" name="Q20_2_0" autocomplete="off" value="27" class="sr-only" onchange="$('#Q20_2_0_change').val('1');wiz.reload();" aria-describedby="Q20_2_0Text" required=""> Compliant </label>`

As you can see the IDs are in the form of Q20_*_0-A27, where * ranges from 0-15.

My aim is to click on these elements / buttons to 'activate them, which loads the page to change the clicked button into:

example with #1.

`<label class="btn btn-primary active"> <input type="radio" id="Q20_0_0-A27" name="Q20_0_0" autocomplete="off" value="27" class="sr-only" onchange="$('#Q20_0_0_change').val('1');wiz.reload();" aria-describedby="Q20_0_0Text" required=""> Compliant </label>`

Below is my code, and I can't seem to identify the right element

```
    try:
        # Find the link with the specified text and class
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'label.btn.btn-primary input[id^="Q20_"][id$="-A27"]')
        print(f'Number of elements found: {len(elements)}')
        for element in elements:
            element_id = element.get_attribute('id')
            print(f'Element ID: {element_id}')
            element.click()
            input("Press Enter to continue...")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        # The element was not found, so wait and try again
        time.sleep(1)
        print("retrying")
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see the IDs are in the form of Q20_*_0-A27, where * ranges
> from 0-15.

You can use the built-in [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function:

```py
for num in range(0,28):
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'#Q20_{num}_0-A27')).click()
```

---

I haven't tested, but you might be able to use a more generic CSS selector altogether:

```
label.btn
```